# yii.activeform.js generate invalid validation js script

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

in a ok project，it should like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#form-signup').yiiActiveForm({
                            "username": {
                                "validate": function(attribute, value, messages) {
                                    yii.validation.required(value, messages, {
                                        "message": "Username\u4e0d\u80fd\u4e3a\u7a7a\u3002"
                                    });
                                    yii.validation.string(value, messages, {
                                        "message": "Username\u5fc5\u987b\u662f\u4e00\u6761\u5b57\u7b26\u4e32\u3002",
                                        "min": 2,
                                        "tooShort": "Username\u5e94\u8be5\u5305\u542b\u81f3\u5c112\u4e2a\u5b57\u7b26\u3002",
                                        "max": 255,
                                        "tooLong": "Username\u53ea\u80fd\u5305\u542b\u81f3\u591a255\u4e2a\u5b57\u7b26\u3002",
                                        "skipOnEmpty": 1
                                    });
                                },
                                "id": "signupform-username",
                                "name": "username",
                                "validateOnChange": true,
                                "validateOnType": false,
                                "validationDelay": 200,
                                "container": ".field-signupform-username",
                                "input": "#signupform-username",
                                "error": ".help-block"
                            },
</script>
```

but in my project,when i enter email or username that is invalid,no hints or error shows! when i check the code generated by yii,i see null args of yiiActiveForm

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#form-signup').yiiActiveForm([], []);
    });
</script>
```

who can tell me why? IS there anything wrong with the vendor folder?

Comment: Show us your model rules and form view

Answer (score 0):

This might be because your model class is not set up to be in the right scenario, causing validation to be skipped.  Please check the documentation on this topic:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios

If you want certain rules to be applied on the current view, you need to set the scenario when you create the instance of your model :

```
// scenario is set as a property
$model = new User;
$model->scenario = 'login';

// scenario is set through configuration
$model = new User(['scenario' => 'login']);
```

In your model, the case above User, you would have this function:

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class User extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function scenarios()
    {
         return [
            'login' => ['username', 'password'],
            //more scenarios would follow here...
         ];
    }
}
```